# python linkedlist append tuples

Tags: python, tuples, singly-linked-list

I need to print the items added.

```
 class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data= [(None,None)], number = None, letter = None, tail = None):
        self.letter = data[0][0]
        self.number = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

    def insert(self, val):
        new = LinkedList(val)
        new.tail = self.data
        self.data = new

    def printer(self,curr):
        while curr:
            print(curr.letter, curr.number)
            curr = curr.tail

new = LinkedList()
new.insert([("A", 1)])
new.insert([("B", 2)])
new.insert([("C", 3)])
new.printer(new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made a very small error,change your insert function to

```
def insert(self, val):
        new = LinkedList(val)
        new.tail = self.tail
        self.tail = new
```

your `LinkedList` has no `data` attribute, its using `tail` as the "data" attribute